# How to rotate a Pixmap on the fly on LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, awt, pixmap

This question is not relevant to [How to draw rotated image on pixmap (LibGDX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441928/how-to-draw-rotated-image-on-pixmap-libgdx), my case is i want to rotate a 2x7 image, and that code does not work.
Someone knows how to rotate the pixmap?

Currently I use BufferedImages but i cant use that on Android.

Edit:
The code above only works on rotations of 90, and i want to rotate in any degree w/o losing any data.

Examples, try to imagine this as a pixmap;

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I want it to rotate into, 45 for this example.

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,7
0,0,0,0,0,6,7
0,0,0,0,5,6,0
0,0,0,4,5,0,0
0,0,3,4,0,0,0
0,2,3,0,0,0,0
1,2,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and 90 for example

```
7,7
6,6
5,5
4,4
3,3
2,2
1,1
```

And i want to rotate into negative values too, like -45

```
1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,2,0,0,0,0,0
0,2,3,0,0,0,0
0,0,3,4,0,0,0
0,0,0,4,5,0,0
0,0,0,0,5,6,0
0,0,0,0,0,6,7
0,0,0,0,0,0,7
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to explain your problem better. It really seems like the same question you're linking.

Comment: Im trying to rotate a 2x7 image on headerlees app. But that code seems to be working only with YxY not for YxZ images.